# CLION does not recognize the function "sem_timedwait"

Tags: c, process, semaphore

I use the IDE "CLion" to code in - and practice - the programming language C.

Trying to solve an exercise, in which I have to implement the function "sem_timedwait(...)", I sadly had to find out, that the IDE does not recognize this function until I create the function in my code by myself, even though I have already implemented the needed header files.

The following error pops up in the affected line:

`Implicit declaration of function 'sem_timedwait' is invalid in C99. Did you mean 'sem_trywait'?`

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

edit: code section added.

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

void *work(void *arg) {

[...]
struct timespec time;
        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &time)) {
            perror("Error at clock_gettime(..)");
            exit(1);
        }
        time.tv_sec += max_prepTime();  //  function which returns an int 

        if (sem_timedwait(&(recipe[i]->sem), &time)) {
            if (errno == ETIMEDOUT) {
                perror("Error at sem_timedwait");
                reset();     // calls my own function, in the case, that the semaphore could not be reached in the given time  
            }
        }

        [...]
}
```

I removed every part of the code which is irrelevant for this part and only left the declaration of the struct timespec "time", to make it clear, where the variable "time" comes from.
I hope that I did not make my code unclear or confusing by leaving the - in this section - missing part out.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [mre] that still shows the issue. Probably you call `sem_timedwait()` before the declaration is visible.

Comment: @thebusybee Thank you! Looks like you're from Germany, too. I edited my post by adding the most relevant part of my code to my post. I hope that this makes things more clear.

Comment: Hm, what I wonder now: Is it the IDE that refuses to know the function, or the compiler if you build? -- There is this hint in the manpage: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600 " You might want to check this.

Comment: @thebusybee I think that the IDE is the problem here, since the error showed up before I've built the project.

Comment: So you might need to define that macro in the IDE.